# Cross-hair display on chart

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I am using two stock charts (one is candlestick and second is stochastics - line chart) one below the another.

It would be great if a cross-hair can be displayed so that I can correlate the two charts.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution.
Maybe, this is useful to somebody else also.

[www.mlin.net](http://www.mlin.net)
click on "CrossHair" link on left side.

This small application creates a cross-hair (for any application, not only LOffice).

Comment: BTW, This solution is for Windows only. Appreciate if anybody throws some light on how to do it for Linux box?